# Слово вылезает за пределы экрана

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

возникла трудность. у меня имеется текст в блоке H1

```html
<section id="intro" class="full-height">
 <div class="content vertical-center">
  <h2>Делаем хорошие косметические ремонты</h2>
     </div>
</section>
```

Собственно CSS который задает ему ширину в 100vh  и выравнивает по центу. В итоге имеем стандартное масштабирование которое отлично работает при изменении ширины экрана. (По слову строчке). Но вот есть загвоздка, при разрешении экрана 320px слово "Косметические" вылезает за край экрана и получается только "Косметичес" хотя до края экрана (с левой стороны еще есть место), и по сути слово должно поместиться.

Погуглив внес некоторые коррективы в header index.html но увы не помогло:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1200"/>
<meta property="og:image:height" content="630"/>
```

Какие тонкости могут быть тут?

Comment: _"ширину в 100vh"_ - что-то здесь не то...

Comment: wh прошу прощения

Comment: Тем более не то. Может всё-таки `vw` или высоту?

Comment: Все не то указал. Для body у меня прописано следующее
 height: auto;
  min-height: 100%; 
 text-align: center;
После чего конкретно для H2
.intro h2 {
  font-size: 8em;
  line-height: 1.0;
  padding: 1em 0em;
  margin-bottom: .6em;

Comment: Возможно Вам нужно обнулить margin/padding для body/html

Comment: Это есть для `HTML, BODY, H1, H2, padding: 0;
  margin: 0;`

Answer (score 2):

если слово не влазит даже при нулевых значениях границ `padding:0 margin:0`, остается единственное правильное решение - уменьшить шрифт для маленьких экранов.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  h2 {
    font-size: 3rem;
  }
}
```

Comment: и вместо em лучше использовать rem

Comment: неправда, не лучше, все зависит от дизайна. Нужно выбрать оптимальное решение, где лучше использовать em и rem. Совершенно бессмысленная идея использовать переназначение rem при уменьшении экрана. Почему тогда сразу не задать величину в px?

Comment: Если блок со шрифтом 2em лежит внутри блока со шрифтом 3em - то текст во внутреннем блоке будет 96px. Если блок со шрифтом 2rem лежит внутри блока со шрифтом 3rem - то текст во внутреннем блоке будет 48px, не зависимо от родителя. Поэтому я рекомендую использовать rem вместо em. https://jsfiddle.net/e9pb4oqw/3/

Answer (score 1):

А если вот так?
Чтобы увидеть результат, раскрывайте на всю страницу, уменьшая и увеличивая ее по ширине

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.fitText = function(kompressor, options) {
    var compressor = kompressor || 1,
      settings = $.extend({
        'minFontSize': Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY,
        'maxFontSize': Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY
      }, options);
    return this.each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      var resizer = function() {
        $this.css('font-size', Math.max(Math.min($this.width() / (compressor * 100), parseFloat(settings.maxFontSize)), parseFloat(settings.minFontSize)));
      };
      resizer();
      $(window).on('resize.fittext orientationchange.fittext', resizer);
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#title").fitText(1.1, {
    minFontSize: '1%',
    maxFontSize: '500%'
  });
});
```

```css
h2 {
  font-size: 500%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="intro" class="full-height">
  <div class="content vertical-center">
    <div class="title" id="title">
      <h2>Делаем хорошие косметические ремонты</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```