# Сделать текст шириной с родительский элемент динамического размера

Tags: css

У меня есть элемент динамического размера (`inline`). В нём есть несколько элементов, одним из которых является текст. Как сделать так, чтобы ширина текста была шириной `inline`-элемента и не вызывала расширения?

**EDIT:** Я немного переосмыслил структуру и реализовал родительский блок как `flex`. Может быть, это поможет?

Comment: с инлайн-элементом так сделать не получится, задай ему, например, `display: inline-block`

Comment: тут много вариантов от маргинов и падингов с процентным соотношением и вплодь до js а там еще куча.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то [вот как вариант](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/785800/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0/1062133#1062133)
Чтобы увидеть результат, раскрывайте на всю страницу, уменьшая и увеличивая ее по ширине

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.fitText = function(kompressor, options) {
    var compressor = kompressor || 1,
      settings = $.extend({
        'minFontSize': Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY,
        'maxFontSize': Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY
      }, options);
    return this.each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      var resizer = function() {
        $this.css('font-size', Math.max(Math.min($this.width() / (compressor * 100), parseFloat(settings.maxFontSize)), parseFloat(settings.minFontSize)));
      };
      resizer();
      $(window).on('resize.fittext orientationchange.fittext', resizer);
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#title").fitText(1.1, {
    minFontSize: '1%',
    maxFontSize: '300%'
  });
});
```

```css
h2 {
  font-size: 300%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="intro" class="full-height">
  <div class="content vertical-center">
    <div class="title" id="title">
      <h2>Текст шириной с родительский элемент динамического размера</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```